# Move Order Total Incl. Tax Order after the Total Excl. Tax in Order Summary in magento2

Tags: magento2.3

Hello  everyone how can I Move Order Total Incl. Tax Order after the Total Excl. Tax in Order Summary in **magento2** checkout page .
[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You're using One Step Checkout extension or default Magento checkout ?

Comment: using extension one page checkout

Comment: In default Magento checkout sequence is coming by default Excluding tax and then Including tax. You need to check your opc extension first. Which company's Extension you have ?

Comment: Can you please check is there any directory available in your OPC extension ?

**view/frontend/web/template/checkout**

Comment: yes it has this dirctory

Comment: I've added my answer, Please let me know if this helps you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **"Order Total Incl. Tax"** and **"Order Total Excl. Tax"** are coming from this file in default Magento

> vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html

So you can override this here in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html

and you can change that content based on your requirement.

But if you're using OPC (One Page Checkout) module for checkout then you can find this file first

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html

and you can override this file in your custom theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/web/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html

and you can change that order here.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution helpful to you ?

Comment: there is no file summary/subtotal.html inside one page checkout module

Comment: Then you can copy your vendor file into your theme first option in my answer and check